# How old is James McGill?

Tags: character, better-call-saul

In Breaking Bad, Saul looked like a man in his late 40s. I want to know - at the beginning of Better Call Saul, how old is James McGill?

Comment: GalacticNinja's should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Breaking Bad Wiki](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Saul_Goodman) (I have no idea where they get this stuff...), Saul is in his late 40's during that series.  Since Better Call Saul is supposed to take place 6 years prior to Breaking Bad, you can assume he's supposed to be in his early-to-mid 40's at the beginning of BCS.

Answer (score 4):

#### 41 years old

In *Better Call Saul* Season 5 Episode 7, "JMM", in the scene where Jimmy and Kim were applying for their marriage license, Jimmy's date of birth on his driver's license was revealed — **November 12, 1960.**

[image: Jimmy McGill's driver's license]

[Season 1 was set in May-July 2002](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Better_Call_Saul_Timeline#Season_1_Timeline), so Jimmy was 41 at the beginning of *Better Call Saul*.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.